# How to reload templates without reloading server?

Tags: java, velocity, spark-framework

I'm working on an application in Java/Spark framework and I'm using the Apache Velocity template engine. My problem is, that every time I change anything in the templates, I have to reload the whole server. Is there a way to enable some kind of hot-swapping to be able to work on the templates without reloading the whole server?

```
private final VelocityEngine velocityEngine;

public VelocityTemplateEngine() {
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.setProperty("resource.loader", "class");
    properties.setProperty("class.resource.loader.class", "org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.loader.ClasspathResourceLoader");
    properties.setProperty("class.resource.loader.cache", "true");
    properties.setProperty("class.resource.loader.modificationCheckInterval", "2");
    properties.setProperty("velocimacro.library.autoreload", "true");
    properties.setProperty("velocimacro.permissions.allow.inline.to.replace.global", "true");
    velocityEngine = new org.apache.velocity.app.VelocityEngine(properties);
    //velocityEngine.init(); <-- This bit of code does not change anything when uncommented...
}
```

**Solution:**
Solved by changing the *resource.loader* to *file* and *class.resource.loader.class* to *org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.loader.FileResourceLoader*

```
properties.setProperty("resource.loader", "file");
properties.setProperty("class.resource.loader.class", "org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.loader.FileResourceLoader");

properties.setProperty("file.resource.loader.path", root + "/src/main/resources/"); // "root" points to the app folder

properties.setProperty("class.resource.loader.cache", "true"); // Enable cache
properties.setProperty("class.resource.loader.modificationCheckInterval", "2"); // Check for new files every 2 seconds
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution Jaboc! Now I'm able to use the performance optimization of caching, and upload .vms without restarting the server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

1. Initialize a velocity engine instance .  VelocityEngine x  = new VelocityEngine();
2. Set properties :

   ```
    file.resource.loader.class= FileResourceLoader classname
    file.resource.loader.path=  template location
    file.resource.loader.cache= true
    file.resource.loader.modificationCheckInterval= duration in which you want to reload the templates
   ```
3. x.int();

Important point here is that you don't initialize velocity engine again on every request. Do something like this while creating velocity engine object :

```
  VelocityEngine x;   // instance variable

  if(x==null)
  {
   x = new VelocityEngine();
   x.init();
   }
  else
  {
   x;
   }
```

Comment: I have tried this before with no success whatsoever.

Comment: For me this pattern worked fine. There might be some minor flaw in your code. Can you post in a bit detail.

Comment: You are using classpath resource loader. Try using FileResource loader.

Comment: Could you please drop me an example? I'm a total noob to Velocity.

Comment: here are some examples : http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/org.apache.velocity.app.VelocityEngine

Comment: What should i put as a value for the "file.resource.loader.path" property? I've tried about 10 different paths and not a single one seems to work. I always get an error, saying that the template was not found.

Comment: Nevermind I've solved this problem by getting the absolute path to the app with "new File(".").getCanonicalPath()" and added "/src/main/templates" to it.